# Gnuplot date limitation (2038?)

Tags: awk, gnuplot

I'm finding a rare limitation in gnuplot, so it seems it can't work with dates after the year 2037. This is the code I'm using:

```
myTimeFmt  = '%d/%m/%Y'
DateStart  = '01/01/2038'
DateEnd    = '31/12/2038'
SecsPerDay = 86400

set print $Data
    do for [t=strptime(myTimeFmt,DateStart):strptime(myTimeFmt,DateEnd):SecsPerDay] {
        print strftime(myTimeFmt,t)
    }
set print

print $Data
```

This works for the year 2037. Trying it with the year 2038 returns the following error:

```
no datablock named $Data
```

With the year 2039 and so on, the code returns the date `13/12/1901`.

Is there any solution for my code to make it work? Or will I have to create the $Data content with another tool? Which one? Could I do that with **awk** (supported in gnuplot)?

Some more information:

- Version: `gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 5`
- Distro: `Debian 4.9.258-1`
- Kernel: `4.9.0-15-amd64`
- Arch: `x86_64`

Comment: could be related to the fact that 2^31-1 seconds after the epoch occurs during 2038-01-19

Comment: Interesting! What does it mean? Another CPU architecture could compute this?

Comment: Might help to specify which version you're using, that works fine for me with 5.4 (i.e. current in ArchLinux).  A smaller example, would be `print strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 2**32)` giving `2106-02-07`, which presumably gives something else for you.

Comment: Sam, it returns the same for me. How is that possible? (I'm using `gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 5` under Debian 9).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise which issue you were struggling with.  Seems to be due to gnuplot switching from integer to floating point when dealing with later dates.  Think you want to use `while` instead, will post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Gnuplot expert, but think it's to do with `for` loops only working with integer values.  You can work around by doing something like:

```
t = strptime(myTimeFmt,DateStart)
te = strptime(myTimeFmt,DateEnd)
while (t < te) {
    print strftime(myTimeFmt,t)
    t = t + SecsPerDay
}
```

That way I get the iteration happening as normal.

Otherwise, you could rewrite to something like:

```
ts = strptime(myTimeFmt, DateStart)
te = strptime(myTimeFmt, DateEnd)
do for [day = 0 : (te - ts) / SecsPerDay] {
    t = ts + day * SecsPerDay
    print strftime(myTimeFmt,t)
}
```

Which might result in less floating point rounding errors if you increment by different values (e.g. if you want to increment by 0.1 seconds you'd run into things like [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1358308)).